# Very large key value pair in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, key

I am brand new to Hadoop and my current complexity of program is limited to the complexity of wordcount. I am trying to understand the fundamental architecture of Hadoop so that I can architect my solutions better.

One of the big questions I have is how does Hadoop handle large Key value pairs at block boundaries? Suppose I have a key value pair of size 10MB (For example, if the value is an entire 10MB file) and suppose I use a sequence file. How does Hadoop handle this at its block boundaries? Does it split the split into two parts and save it in two different blocks or does it realize that the key value pair is very large and hence rather than splitting, it just creates a new block for the entire key value pair?

Comment: Good question! I think it splits it in the middle of the value and then reconstitutes it at runtime (that is, it ignores the key/value boundaries)... but I am not sure enough to provide an official answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default block size in HDFS is 64 MB. If a key/value pair is 10 MB then it might/might not be split across blocks.

- If the 1st KV pair is 60 MB and the 2nd is 10 MB. Then then 2nd KV pair has only 4 MB space left in the 1st block (when block size if 64MB). So, 4 MB of the 2nd KV is stored in the 1st block and the remaining 6 MB is stored in the second block.
- If the 1st KV pair is 40 MB and the 2nd is 10 MB. Then then 2nd KV pair has 24 MB space left in the first block (when block size if 64MB). So, the 2nd KV is stored completely in the 1st block and not split.

When using a SequenceFile a mapper doesn't know where the start of a record is in a block, so a sync is added to SequenceFiles automatically by the Hadoop framework. According to the [Hadoop:The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

> A sync point is a point in the stream that can be used to resynchronize with a record boundary if the reader is “lost”—for example, after seeking to an arbitrary position in the stream. Sync points are recorded by SequenceFile.Writer, which inserts a special entry to mark the sync point every few records as a sequence file is being written. Such entries are small enough to incur only a modest storage overhead—less than 1%. Sync points always align with record boundaries.

When a map task starts processing a block, it will [seek](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.Reader.html#seek%28long%29) the first sync point and start processing records from there. And when it reached the end of the block, it will seek the the first sync point of the next block and the data is transferred up to that point over the network to the mapper for processing.

To summarize, Hadoop frameworks is record aware even if the record is split across blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That answered my question but I guess this also means that there is a pretty big overhead of transferring large amount of data between nodes when large key value pair gets split. (In your example, either 6MB or 4MB of transfer required). SO may be it does not make sense to have large key-value pairs. Am I correct?

Comment: If there is a large kv pair, then HDFS block size can be increased from the default value of 64 MB.